# rebuilding scikit-learn under anaconda on OSX 10.9

Tags: python, macos, scikit-learn, anaconda

I am using scikit-learn 0.15.2 installed on mac osx 10.9 using anaconda Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.0.1.

I modified some code inside scikit-learn specifically the gradient_boosting.py. I tried to rebuild scikit-learn (inside the anaconda directory) using:
`python setup.py build`

but I am getting:

```
gcc: src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp
gcc: error: src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Not sure if installing libsvm is the right way to go or is there a better way to rebuild scikit-learn under mac osx and anaconda?

Comment: How did you download the source code of scikit-learn 0.15.2?

Comment: The patched libsvm source is included in the source distribution of scikit-learn: there is no need to install libsvm separately.

Comment: I am directly modifying the code in the anaconda directory:
anaconda/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.15.0-np18py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py

Comment: @Kasra: please note that inline code spans (`like this`) are not meant for emphasis, they should be used for code within sentences only. See this [Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right/135113#135113) for more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just modify python code and you don't modify C code (e.g. by modifying `.pyx` files and re-running the cython command on them) there is no need to rebuild.

Comment: I tried directly modifying the python code (gradient_boosting.py) but it doesn't seem to take effect. I do see a _gradient_boosting.so file but no .pyx files.

Comment: You need to download the source for scikit-learn, either from github or from PyPI.